# Mutiple Where subqueries in Hive doesn't work

Tags: hadoop, hive

I have a Query like below:

```
SELECT T.MTH_END_DT, T.SRC_SYS_CD, T.BTCH_ID
FROM PROD_RCRR.BAL_CNTRL_LOG T
WHERE T.SRC_SYS_CD='SL'
AND T.MTH_END_DT in (SELECT(MAX(MTH_END_DT)) FROM PROD_RCRR.BAL_CNTRL_LOG)
AND T.BTCH_ID in (SELECT(MAX(BTCH_ID )) FROM PROD_RCRR.BAL_CNTRL_LOG)
```

A error message shows Hive only can support one "in" clause. Anyone can give me a solution?

Answer (score 2):

You can replace the whole thing with Join ON clause

```
SELECT
    T.MTH_END_DT
  , T.SRC_SYS_CD
  , T.BTCH_ID
FROM PROD_RCRR.BAL_CNTRL_LOG T
JOIN ( SELECT
          MAX(MTH_END_DT) ENDT
        , MAX(BTCH_ID )   BTCH
       FROM PROD_RCRR.BAL_CNTRL_LOG ) X
  ON  T.SRC_SYS_CD='SL'
  AND T.MTH_END_DT = X.ENDT
  AND T.BTCH_ID = X.BTCH
```

Comment: Nice way to use a single join to get both conditions.

Comment: @RachaelLi Thanks for the confirmation. You can check mark the answer as well.